# How to use neural network for regression

Tags: regression, machine-learning, neural-networks, classification

I am new in the field of machine learning, and I am sorry if my question may seem naive to most of you.

I am following the "Machine Learning" course by Andrew Ng on Coursera. 
At this moment, I am studying the concept of neural networks (NN) and their training.

During the course, we use NN for classification problems.

I was wondering if we can apply a similar NN  to a regression problem.

Here is my doubt: the NN proposed, uses the sigmoid as the activation function. The sigmoid has an output between 0 and 1, so I understand why it is useful for classification.

In the case of regression problems, the output has to be a real number, so that I do not understand if this  NN can be used for this type of problem.

Is it only a matter of normalisation? Do I have to use a different activation function?

Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 1):

The Cybenko Universal Approximation Theorem outlines the conditions under which a single-layer neural network with some number of sigmoid hidden activations can be used to approximate a function over a specific domain. Not all functions can be approximated in this manner; see the article for all caveats.

The implication is that we can use neural networks for regression because Cybenko shows that it is at least *theoretically possible* to approximate some functions arbitrarily well under specific circumstances.

For practical purposes, however, there are caveats.
The optimization task of training a neural network is notoriously challenging. Cybenko merely shows that a network *exists* to approximate a class of functions; Cybenko's UAT does not comment on how easy or hard it is to train a given network to approximate the desired function to the desired level of precision in common real-world conditions, such as available data are finite, the data are subject to noise, the underlying true function which we wish to approximate is unknown, etc. Not all functions or settings match the theoretical conditions which Cybenko requires in his theorem.

Nevertheless, despite these challenges, **neural networks are used for regression tasks all the time**, even with sigmoid hidden activations. However, it is more common these days to use ReLU functions and variants because they tend to do better than sigmoid functions. (There are also several universal approximation theorems pertaining to different settings for ReLU networks.)

G. Cybenko, "Approximation by superpositions of a sigmoidal function." *Mathematics of Control, Signals and Systems* volume 2, pp. 303–314(1989)

Answer (score 0):

For a regression, the top (output) layer is usually linear. The loss function is usually Mean Squared Error.

The Universal Approximation Theorems mentioned by Sycorax have a condition that the domain is compact: in non-technical terms, that means that an ANN regressor can be good at interpolation, but should not be expected to extrapolate well.